# Why is this part of the composed proposition false?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Currently I'm studying logic, but I do not understand a certain step. It is the step from row $2$ to $3$. I see that $-q$ is the common factor on both sides of the middle or operator, but I did not succeed in factoring out.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(p \wedge q) \rightarrow \neg(r \vee q) & \equiv \neg(p \wedge q) \vee \neg(r \vee q) \\
& \equiv \neg p \vee \neg q \vee(\neg r \wedge \neg q) \\
& \equiv \neg p \vee \neg q
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I understand that

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\equiv \mathbb{F} \vee(p \wedge q) \\
&\equiv(p \wedge q)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

so that implies that

\begin{equation}
(\neg \boldsymbol{r} \wedge \neg q)
\end{equation}

is false.

Do I miss a rule or should it be obvious from the K-map?

Whole question + solution:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I included the whole question to make sure I didnot include essential information

Comment: I mixed two past papers. Now it should be 'correct'

Comment: It's definitely an equivalence. Do you know what absorption is?

Comment: I checked it on wikipedia. But I don't see yet how the prove equivalence

Comment: @TenO'Four Now it looks correct I added a proof.

Comment: @Voilet Flame, while correct I'm not sure it will help Tim much. They're probs looking for a list of equivalences — comp sci loves their equivalences lol

Comment: @Tim, this is [absorption](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_law) — $\lnot q\lor (\lnot r\land\lnot q)\equiv\lnot q$

Comment: @Tim, here's [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536111/explain-the-absorption-law) of the law (see the last answer)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to point out a mistake in your reasoning. You say:

> I understand that

> \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> &\equiv \mathbb{F} \vee(p \wedge q) \\
> &\equiv(p \wedge q)
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}

> so that implies that

> \begin{equation}
> (\neg \boldsymbol{r} \wedge \neg q)
> \end{equation}

> is false.

No, that does not follow. (and obviously $\neg r \land \neg q$ is *not* equivalent to $False$)

Consider: $p \lor p \equiv p$ ... so by your logic, we would have to have that $p \equiv False$?

Clearly something is wrong with your logic. At its core, what you are doing is this:

We know that if $\psi \equiv False$, then $\phi \lor \psi \equiv \phi$. But the converse is *not* true: if $\phi \lor \psi \equiv \phi$, then $\psi \equiv False$. In effect, you are making the logical fallacy of affirming the consequent.

OK, but why does the converse not hold? What follows below will provide some further insight.

As a general helpful principle, note that $p \lor (p \land q) \equiv p$:

$$p \lor (p \land q) \equiv p$$

$$\overset{Identity}{\equiv}$$

$$(p \land \top) \lor (p \land q)$$

$$\overset{Distribution}{\equiv}$$

$$p \land (\top \lor q)$$

$$\overset{Annihilation}{\equiv}$$

$$p  \land \top$$

$$\overset{Identity}{\equiv}$$

$$p$$

That first step is a little tricky, but you can also think of this as:

$p + pq = p(1+q) = p1 = p$

This principle is so common, that is has a name:

**Absorption**

$p + pq = p$

and its dual: $p(p+q) = p$

So, if you apply Absorption to your statement, you get:

$$\neg p \lor \neg q \lor (\neg r \land \neg q)$$

$$\overset{Absorption}{\equiv}$$

$$\neg p \vee \neg q$$

Yeah, it's that easy. So make sure to put Absorption in your Boolean Algebra toolkit!

Also if you look at what happens in a K-Map, you'll immediately notice why it's called Absorption:  The one term is 'absorbed' by the other term: *that*'s why it can be removed!

So, going back to your earlier mistake:  $p \lor p \equiv p$ not because $p \equiv False$, but because the second $p$ is already covered by the first $p$.  Put differently: it's not that the second $p$ is doing nothing but because the second $p$ term isn't doing anything *over and above* the first term.

Likewise, $\neg q \lor (\neg r \land \neg q) \equiv \neg q$ not because $\neg r \land \neg q$ is doing nothing, but because it is doing nothing over and above $\neg q$ by itself: the $\neg q$ 'covers', and thus 'absorbs' the $\neg r \land \neg q$ term

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer!

Comment: @Tim You’re welcome!

Comment: It’s a great answer that deserves to be accepted!

Comment: Thanks @VoiletFlame !

Answer (score 3):

> $\neg p\lor \neg q\equiv \neg p \vee \neg q \vee(\neg r \wedge \neg q) \\$

Is indeed true, one direction of the equivalence is trivial, for the other direction suppose that  $\neg p \lor \neg q \lor (\neg r \land  \neg q) $ is true then we *must* have that **at least one** of the disjuncts is true. Now suppose  that $(\neg r \land \neg q$) is true then we immediately have that $\neg q$ is true and so we get $\neg p\lor \neg q$ is true. If the other disjunct is true then we have a triviality.